# Verificar em JavaScript se String possui cadeia de x números

Tags: javascript, string, include

Ola, gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de verificar se uma String possui em JavaScript, por exemplo, 5 numero **em sequencia aleatória** para disparar um evento. Sendo assim:

> abc123de45

Deve ser **false**

> abc13525de

Deve ser **true**

> ab12cde453fgh76i8jk9

Deve ser **false**

Obrigado!

Comment: Sua sequência vai ser fixa ou variável?

Comment: Eu pego o valor de um campo textarea em um form e a cada letra digitada a variavel muda:
$(document).on('input', '#content', function(){
var conteudo = $('#content').val();
}

Comment: A dúvida que o @Sorack levantou é sobre a sequência: quer validar somente `12345`, ou vale qualquer sequência? Tipo `23456`, `56789`, `89012` (vai ser circular?).

Comment: ops, perdão.
Serve qualquer sequencia de X números.

Comment: Os números devem ser ordenados? Ou uma sequência de cinco números, ordenados ou não? Ex: ac12458cd

Comment: pode ser uma sequencia aleatória, o importante é ser 5 números seguidos, já editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode utilizar com [`match`](http://String.prototype.match())

```js
var str0 = 'abc123de45'
console.log((str0.match(/[0-9]{5}/) != null));

var str1 = 'abc12345de';
console.log((str1.match(/[0-9]{5}/) != null));
```

Comment: Boa solução usando regex

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma função que monte a sequência e use `.indexOf` para checa-la:

```js
function verificarSequencia(texto, quantidade) {
  var regex = new RegExp('\\d{' + quantidade + '}', 'g');

  return regex.test(texto);
}

console.log('abc123de45', verificarSequencia('abc123de45', 5));
console.log('abc12345de', verificarSequencia('abc12345de', 5));
console.log('ab12cde345fgh67i8jk9', verificarSequencia('ab12cde345fgh67i8jk9', 5));
```

Comment: +1 boa .........

Answer (score 0):

Segundo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/3473971) do SO gringo:

**1) indexOf** - pra ver se a string possui a outra string, vai voltar -1 se nao tiver

**2) (ES6) includes** - use se tiver usando o ES6

```
var string = "foo",
substring = "oo";
string.includes(substring);
```

Acho que esses sao os mais faceis, estou saindo de casa mas depois edito com todos da resposta ;)

Answer (score -2):

Acho melhor somente usar o includes

por exemplo:

lista = "45645,7987,45,79,187,28,"

numero = "456,";

lista.includes(numero) vai retornar falso.

eu usei o delimitador na inclusão da pesquisa e com isso
sempre será único.